# DHCP IP Address / sub interfaces

Tags: networking, dhcp

I've setup a DHCP server for about 120 sub networks and it's working very well, it gives the right IPs from the right subnet / VLAN.

The server listen to Eth0 which has the IP 192.168.111.20 and all other sub interfaces ate eth0.1, eth0.2 and so on, until eth0.120.

Every sub interface has an IP-address from it's own range, e.g. eth0.1 is 10.0.1.10, the issue I have is that if a device is connected to any of the VLans, it works fine, so the device receives an IP from the right range but if I do e.g. "ifconfig /all" in that device it shows me the IP address of the sub interface as the DHCP server IP and not the main IP of eth0 (192.168.111.20), for example: if the client machine is connected to the VLan 15 (eth0.15 with IP address 10.0.15.15 of the sub interface and  range 10.0.15.50-150), then the client machine gets IP address from the right range but   ipconfig shows that the DHCP IP 10.0.15.15 and not the IP Address of the main interface which is eth0 (192.168.111.20). Is this right? As I am replacing our windows 2008 DHCP server with this one (UBUNTU). The windows 2008 DHCP server shows always the IP address of the network card /interface (192.168.111.11) as DHCP server IP address on client's machine, doesn't matter which VLAN or subnet clients machine is connected to but the ubuntu one shows always the IP address of the sub interface / Vlan as DHCP Server IP address and not the IP address of the physical network card.

Is this right or am I doing something wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Solved, the issue was due to the wrong IP-helper in Cisco core switches.

Many thanks

Comment: Set this as solution, please.